# Fetching elements from multiple columns of lists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     A            B             C
  [1,2,3]    ['a','b','c']    ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
  [4,5,6]    ['d','e','f']    ['dd', 'ee', 'ff']
  [7,8,9]    ['g','h','i']    ['gg', 'hh', 'ii']
```

I would like to combine the values from these columns as follows:

```
[[[1,'a', 'aa'], [2,'b','bb'], [3, 'c', 'cc']], [[4,'d','dd'], [5,'e', 'ee'], [6,'f','ff']], [[7,'g','gg'], [8,'h','hh'], [9,'i','ii']]]
```

My idea was to change each column to list like this (which will give a list of list) :

`first = df['A'].values.tolist()` # similarly for other columns

And then zip all lists and iterate through them and fetch corresponding values from each list and create a new list as per the output format. But, I am sure there are better solutions than mine. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are the cells always of length 3?

Comment: no, this is just an example. However, each column will have same number of elements in a list.

Comment: Do you mean each row has the same number of element ? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to map the values.

Comment: yes, each row has same number of elements

Comment: yes, if you are talking about each sublist row wise. However, column wise, it can change.

Comment: If column wise the size of each sublist in each cell is not the same, my solution doesn't work. I'll  delete my solution.

Comment: it can be different column wise. Thanks for your time anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `explode` with `groupby`

```
pd.concat([df[[x]].explode(x) for x in df.columns],axis=1)\
     .apply(lambda x : x.tolist(),axis=1).groupby(level=0).agg(list).tolist()
Out[366]: 
[[[1, 'a', 'aa'], [2, 'b', 'bb'], [3, 'c', 'cc']],
 [[4, 'd', 'dd'], [5, 'e', 'ee'], [6, 'f', 'ff']],
 [[7, 'g', 'gg'], [8, 'h', 'hh'], [9, 'i', 'ii']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

An extreme solution with `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(*x.to_list())), axis=1).to_list()
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 'a', 'aa'), (2, 'b', 'bb'), (3, 'c', 'cc')],
 [(4, 'd', 'dd'), (5, 'e', 'ee'), (6, 'f', 'ff')],
 [(7, 'g', 'gg'), (8, 'h', 'hh'), (9, 'i', 'ii')]]
```